# Python Pandas load dates and range of dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a spreadsheet that lists vacation days for different schools. An example is:

```
            Labor Day    Fall Break    Veterans Day    Random Holiday
DistrictA         9/2         10/14           11/11
DistrictB         9/2   10/13-10/14           11/11       12/17,12/19
```

The holidays are either single dates, ranges (separated by hyphen), or multiple dates (separated by commas).

I am trying to create an array where given a District name and a date, it will simply return if this is a holiday or not (True/False).

The basics of what I have are:

```
import pandas as pd
vacation = pd.read_excel("Vacations.xlsx")
v = {}
for index, row in vacation.iterrows():
    v[row[0]] = row.values.tolist()[1:]
print(v)
```

This creates a dictionary where the key is the District name and the values are an array of the time range values (`datetime` object, `Timestamp` object, string (if date is range or multiple), nan (Not a #), or NaT (not a time)

One idea I had is to go through each date value and append the dates to a new list. So for example:

```
'DistrictA': [datetime.datetime(2019,9,2), '10/13-10/15', Timestamp('2019-11-11 00:00:00')]
```

would turn into

```
'DistrictA': [datetime.datetime(2019,9,2), datetime.datetime(2019,10,13), datetime.datetime(2019,10,14), datetime.datetime(2019,10,15), datetime.datetime(2019,11,11)]
```

But I am sure there is a much better way. What is the best way to check if a given date is a holiday?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to have already been answered using `pandas.tseries.holiday` https://stackoverflow.com/a/24645696/5298555

Comment: These are not standard US holidays. It is set by school district. Each district has different days off