# Airflow custom schedule_interval setup

Tags: cron, airflow, schedule, directed-acyclic-graphs

is there a way to set up/write a custom schedule_interval in an Airflow DAG?
What I'm looking for is a way to set up a schedule when DAG runs on a daily basis except of holidays (like Christmas, Labor Day, Independence Day etc.)

It is not possible to achieve with standard cron expressions. Any help/guide is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PythonBranchOperator` or create a new operator that inherits `BaseBranchOperator` where you implement the skipping logic. I believe you'll need a `DummyOperator` as the "skip" branch, and your regular DAG flow as the other arm. For your cron expression, use whatever the normal schedule should be and implement custom skips in the task that's handling branching.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for this type of scheduling but you can solve this with adding `ShortCircuitOperator` to the beginning of your workflow.
This operator execute a python callable. If condition met it continue workflow if condition doesn't met it mark all downstream tasks as skipped.

Possible solution can be:

```
import holidays

def decide(**kwargs):
    # Select country
    us_holidays = holidays.US()
    if str(kwargs['execution_date']) in us_holidays:
        return False # Skip workflow if it's a holiday.
    return True

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='mydag',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    default_args=default_args,
)

start_op = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='start_task',
    python_callable=decide,
    provide_context=True,  # Remove this line if you are using Airflow>=2.0.0
    dag=dag
)
#Replace this with your actual Operator in your workflow.
next_op = Operator(
    task_id='next_task',
    dag=dag
)
start_op >> next_op
```

This solution is based on the answer provided in [Detecting a US Holiday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394235/detecting-a-us-holiday) I didn't test it but it should work. In any case you can replace the logic in `decide` to any method that detects if a date is a holiday or not.