# How to apply a two-variable function to a pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a pandas dataframe, it has a column with date (datetime) and a column with day of the week (Mon-Sun). I would like to create a new column that would show whether it's a weekday, weekend or a holiday.
Including a snapshot of dataframe for reference.

This is the function I wrote, I'm listing the holidays one by one since there are only 6.

```
def day_type (day_month, day_week):
    if (day_month == '2013-01-01' or day_month == '2013-05-27' or day_month == '2013-07-04' \
        or day_month == '2013-09-02' or day_month == '2013-11-28' or day_month == '2013-12-25'):
        return "H"
    elif day_week == "Saturday" or day_week =="Sunday":
        return "WE"
    else:
        return "WD"
```

I am then executing the function with apply where LoadData['Date'] is my day_month and LoadData['DoW'] is my day_week.

```
LoadData["DayType"] = LoadData[['Date','DoW']].apply(day_type)
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: day_type() missing 1 required positional argument: 'day_week'`

I have tried using lambda as well to apply the function but I got an error as well:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I must be missing something; I've tried this in many different ways and still not getting anywhere.

Comment: `LoadData.apply(lambda x: day_type(x["Date"],x["DoW"]),axis=1)`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The datetime module has all that. **Weekday/weekend:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/9847213/12846804. **Holiday:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/2394235/12846804. You're escaping the duplicate flag because you're sort of asking 2 questions in one :)

Comment: Minimal reproducible example: Share something like df.head().to_dict() for specific solutions.

Comment: @not_speshal Tried that and got value error

Comment: @OCa I've been there. I already have day of the week identified and The USFederalHolidayCalendar() that I imported into Python lists 10 Federal holidays and I only need the 6, it would require an additional step to pick and choose which holidays I need for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative option:

```
LoadData = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date', 'DoW'])
for num, date in enumerate(pd.date_range('20130101', '20130108')):
    LoadData.loc[num] = [date, date.strftime('%A')]
holiday_list = ['2013-01-01', '2013-05-27', '2013-07-04', '2013-09-02', '2013-11-28', '2013-12-25']
conds = [LoadData.Date.isin(holiday_list), LoadData.DoW.isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday'])]
choice = ['H', 'WD']
LoadData['flag'] = np.select(conds, choice, default = 'WE')
print(LoadData)

 Date        DoW flag
0 2013-01-01    Tuesday    H
1 2013-01-02  Wednesday   WE
2 2013-01-03   Thursday   WE
3 2013-01-04     Friday   WE
4 2013-01-05   Saturday   WD
5 2013-01-06     Sunday   WD
6 2013-01-07     Monday   WE
7 2013-01-08    Tuesday   WE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're dataframe looks like, but try using [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

As an example on a dummy data (similar to what you want would be):

```
def temp_func(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2

df = pd.DataFrame({'arr1': np.random.rand(10), 'arr2': np.random.rand(10)})
df = df.assign( arr3= lambda r: temp_func(r['arr1'], r['arr2']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use panda's [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) function like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# construct a dummy dataframe
LoadData = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date', 'DoW'])
for num, date in enumerate(pd.date_range('20130101', '20130108')):
    LoadData.loc[num] = [date, date.strftime('%A')]

holiday_list = ['2013-01-01', '2013-05-27', '2013-07-04', '2013-09-02', '2013-11-28', '2013-12-25']
LoadData['DayType'] = 'WE'
LoadData['DayType'] = LoadData['DayType'].where(LoadData['DoW'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday']), 'WD')
LoadData['DayType'] = LoadData['DayType'].where(~LoadData['Date'].isin(holiday_list), 'H')
```

You will need to repeatedly assign values to DayType using this method but I think it's worth a try

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to approach this is to use a function that takes a row (which is a pandas series) of the dataframe as the single input, and then apply that. This is how you use `lambda` to create such a function out of the one you already have:

```
LoadData['DayType'] = LoadData.apply(lambda row: day_type(row['Date'], row['DoW']), 1)
```

That second parameter `axis = 1` for `.apply` tells it to apply the function to each row, the default behavior (`axis = 0`) is columns.

Rather than using lambda, you could also re-write your `day_type` function to handle this itself:

```
def day_type(row):
    day_month = row['Date']
    day_week = row['DoW']
    if (day_month == '2013-01-01' or day_month == '2013-05-27' or day_month == '2013-07-04' \
        or day_month == '2013-09-02' or day_month == '2013-11-28' or day_month == '2013-12-25'):
        return "H"
    elif day_week == "Saturday" or day_week =="Sunday":
        return "WE"
    else:
        return "WD"
```

Then

```
LoadData['DayType'] = LoadData.apply(day_type, 1)
```

Comment: This is the function I was looking for, however when I ran this code the new column only retuned, WE and WD, but not H for holiday