# German holidays in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there any function that considers German bank holidays in Matlab? I need to mark German holidays as part of a "weekend and holiday matrix" over several years in Matlab to estimate mean values for i) weekends and holidays and for ii) workdays.

Comment: Certainly not. You need to download the german band holidays data somewhere, save it as a file and then import it in matlab.

Comment: Related: [Holiday files for G20 countries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1029794/5358968)

Comment: MATLAB has a lot of inbuilts but this seems like too far! However you can probably find that information somewhere and make a function yourself.

Comment: There an inbuilt `holidays` function , but you have to manually add the dates plus you must have a financial toolbox which isnt a very good solution , so your best bet is to find and add these dates manually to a datetime vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab doesn't has a function like holidays to other countries. You can implement a function and load the datetimes.
Here you can see an implementation like holidays to african public holidays:

[African holidays](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43862-south-african-public-holidays)

[File function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43862-south-african-public-holidays/content/holidaysRSA.m)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a **Webservice** via ReST that delivers banking holidays / **public holidays in germany**.

E.g.  http://pubhday.fho.one/2/isWorkDay?date=2016-11-01&state=DE-BY&license=!!Testkey!!&postalcode=85614

Found at:  https://www.smart-webservice.com