# How to get the previous working day excluding weekend and holidays

Tags: vb.net, uipath, uipath-studio

I would like to get the previous working day excluding weekend and holiday using VB Net in **UiPath**.
I referenced this:[how-to-determine-if-a-date-is-a-holiday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865412/how-to-determine-if-a-date-is-a-holiday), however I get errors when put the code.
I tried add `Sub` and `End Sub`, but I still get the same error.

Here's the code

```
Sub GetWorkdays()
Dim todayVar As Date = Today
Debug.Print(isHoliday(todayVar.AddDays(1)))

End Sub
Function isHoliday(ByVal dt As Date)
Return getHolidayList(dt.Year).Any(Function(x) x = dt)
End Function

Public Function getHolidayList(ByVal vYear As Integer) As List(Of Date)

Dim FirstWeek As Integer = 1
Dim SecondWeek As Integer = 2
Dim ThirdWeek As Integer = 3
Dim FourthWeek As Integer = 4
Dim LastWeek As Integer = 5

Dim HolidayList As New List(Of Date)

'   http://www.usa.gov/citizens/holidays.shtml      
'   http://archive.opm.gov/operating_status_schedules/fedhol/2013.asp

' New Year's Day            Jan 1
HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 1, 1))

' Martin Luther King, Jr. third Mon in Jan
HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 1, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, ThirdWeek))

' Washington's Birthday third Mon in Feb
HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 2, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, ThirdWeek))

' Memorial Day          last Mon in May
HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 5, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, LastWeek))

' Independence Day      July 4
HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 7, 4))

' Labor Day             first Mon in Sept
HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 9, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeek))

' Columbus Day          second Mon in Oct
HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 10, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, SecondWeek))

' Veterans Day          Nov 11
HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 11, 11))

' Thanksgiving Day      fourth Thur in Nov
HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 11, 1), DayOfWeek.Thursday, FourthWeek))

' Christmas Day         Dec 25
HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 12, 25))

'saturday holidays are moved to Fri; Sun to Mon
For i As Integer = 0 To HolidayList.Count - 1
    Dim dt As Date = HolidayList(i)
    If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
        HolidayList(i) = dt.AddDays(-1)
    End If
    If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        HolidayList(i) = dt.AddDays(1)
    End If
Next

'return
Return HolidayList

End Function

 Private Function GetNthDayOfNthWeek(ByVal dt As Date, ByVal DayofWeek As Integer, ByVal 
 WhichWeek As Integer) As Date
'specify which day of which week of a month and this function will get the date
'this function uses the month and year of the date provided

'get first day of the given date
Dim dtFirst As Date = DateSerial(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1)

'get first DayOfWeek of the month
Dim dtRet As Date = dtFirst.AddDays(6 - dtFirst.AddDays(-(DayofWeek + 1)).DayOfWeek)

'get which week
dtRet = dtRet.AddDays((WhichWeek - 1) * 7)

'if day is past end of month then adjust backwards a week
If dtRet >= dtFirst.AddMonths(1) Then
    dtRet = dtRet.AddDays(-7)
End If

'return
Return dtRet

End Function
```

This is the error:
[image]
How do I solve the errors?

Here's the editor view:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ByVal and WhichWeek need to be on the same line.

```
Sub GetWorkdays()
        Dim todayVar As Date = Today
        Debug.Print(isHoliday(todayVar.AddDays(1)))

    End Sub
    Function isHoliday(ByVal dt As Date)
        Return getHolidayList(dt.Year).Any(Function(x) x = dt)
    End Function

    Public Function getHolidayList(ByVal vYear As Integer) As List(Of Date)

        Dim FirstWeek As Integer = 1
        Dim SecondWeek As Integer = 2
        Dim ThirdWeek As Integer = 3
        Dim FourthWeek As Integer = 4
        Dim LastWeek As Integer = 5

        Dim HolidayList As New List(Of Date)

        '   http://www.usa.gov/citizens/holidays.shtml      
        '   http://archive.opm.gov/operating_status_schedules/fedhol/2013.asp

        ' New Year's Day            Jan 1
        HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 1, 1))

        ' Martin Luther King, Jr. third Mon in Jan
        HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 1, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, ThirdWeek))

        ' Washington's Birthday third Mon in Feb
        HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 2, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, ThirdWeek))

        ' Memorial Day          last Mon in May
        HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 5, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, LastWeek))

        ' Independence Day      July 4
        HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 7, 4))

        ' Labor Day             first Mon in Sept
        HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 9, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeek))

        ' Columbus Day          second Mon in Oct
        HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 10, 1), DayOfWeek.Monday, SecondWeek))

        ' Veterans Day          Nov 11
        HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 11, 11))

        ' Thanksgiving Day      fourth Thur in Nov
        HolidayList.Add(GetNthDayOfNthWeek(DateSerial(vYear, 11, 1), DayOfWeek.Thursday, FourthWeek))

        ' Christmas Day         Dec 25
        HolidayList.Add(DateSerial(vYear, 12, 25))

        'saturday holidays are moved to Fri; Sun to Mon
        For i As Integer = 0 To HolidayList.Count - 1
            Dim dt As Date = HolidayList(i)
            If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
                HolidayList(i) = dt.AddDays(-1)
            End If
            If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                HolidayList(i) = dt.AddDays(1)
            End If
        Next

        'return
        Return HolidayList

    End Function

    Private Function GetNthDayOfNthWeek(ByVal dt As Date, ByVal DayofWeek As Integer,
                                        ByVal WhichWeek As Integer) As Date
        'specify which day of which week of a month and this function will get the date
        'this function uses the month and year of the date provided

        'get first day of the given date
        Dim dtFirst As Date = DateSerial(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1)

        'get first DayOfWeek of the month
        Dim dtRet As Date = dtFirst.AddDays(6 - dtFirst.AddDays(-(DayofWeek + 1)).DayOfWeek)

        'get which week
        dtRet = dtRet.AddDays((WhichWeek - 1) * 7)

        'if day is past end of month then adjust backwards a week
        If dtRet >= dtFirst.AddMonths(1) Then
            dtRet = dtRet.AddDays(-7)
        End If

        'return
        Return dtRet

    End Function
```

Also, not telling us what the error is or which line isn't very helpful...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, ByVal and WhichWeek are already in the same line when I look in the editor. I added what the error says and some pictures.