# SQL - BigQuery - How do I fill in dates from a calendar table?

Tags: sql, date, join, google-bigquery

My goal is to join a sales program table to a calendar table so that there would be a joined table with the full trailing 52 weeks by day, and then the sales data would be joined to it. The idea would be that there are nulls I could COALESCE after the fact. However, my problem is that I only get results without nulls from my sales data table.

The questions I've consulted so far are:

[Join to Calendar Table - 5 Business Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253943/join-to-calendar-table-5-business-days)

[Joining missing dates from calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137130/joining-missing-dates-from-calendar-table) Which points to

[MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

My Calendar table is all 364 days previous to today (today being day 0). And the sales data has a program field, a store field, and then a start date and an end date for the program.

Here's what I have coded:

```
SELECT 
    CAL.DATE,
    CAL.DAY,
    SALES.ITEM,
    SALES.PROGRAM,
    SALES.SALE_DT,
    SALES.EFF_BGN_DT,
    SALES.EFF_END_DT
  FROM 
    CALENDAR_TABLE AS CAL
  LEFT JOIN 
    SALES_TABLE AS SALES
  ON CAL.DATE = SALES.SALE_DT
  WHERE 1=1
    and SALES.ITEM = 1 or SALES.ITEM is null
  ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

What I expected was 365 records with dates where there were nulls and dates where there were filled in records. My query resulted in a few dates with null values but otherwise just the dates where a program exists.

```
   DATE   |  ITEM  | PROGRAM | SALE_DT  | PRGM_BGN  | PRGM_END  |
----------|--------|---------|----------|-----------|-----------|
8/27/2020 |        |         |          |           |           |
8/26/2020 |        |         |          |           |           |
8/25/2020 |        |         |          |           |           |
8/24/2020 |        |         |          |           |           |
6/7/2020  |    1   |    5    | 6/7/2020 | 2/13/2016 |  6/7/2020 |
6/6/2020  |    1   |    5    | 6/6/2020 | 2/13/2016 |  6/7/2020 |
6/5/2020  |    1   |    5    | 6/5/2020 | 2/13/2016 |  6/7/2020 |
6/4/2020  |    1   |    5    | 6/4/2020 | 2/13/2016 |  6/7/2020 |

Date = Calendar day.
Item = Item number being sold.
Program = Unique numeric ID of program.
Sale_Dt = Field populated if at least one item was sold under this program.
Prgm_bgn = First day when item was eligible to be sold under this program.
Prgm_end = Last day when item was eligible to be sold under this program.
```

What I would have expected would have been records between June 7 and August 24 which just had the DATE column populated for each day and null values as what happens in the most recent four records.

I'm trying to understand why a calendar table and what I've written are not providing the in-between dates.

EDIT: I've removed the request for feedback to shorten the question as well as an example I don't think added value. But please continue to give feedback as you see necessary.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :o)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at that right now so I can try to update my question with it.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? "Any feedback" is not a valid SO question. [ask] [help] Also you can google re asking via site:meta.SO or site:meta.SE. (Or ask, but research, including what is on-topic there.) Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Is your `where` clause correct?  Note the order of operations for and/or.  Consider rewriting as `WHERE IFNULL(SALES.ITEM,1) = 1`.

Comment: It didn't seem to make a difference when I removed the where clause all together or used either of the conditions or used both at the same time. So, I left them. (The 1=1 is just something that visually helps me find it and only ever have to type AND when creating conditions).

However, I think I have an answer, so I'm going to paste it as an answer to my question.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more than happy to delete this whole question or have someone else give a better answer, but after staring at the logic in some of the answers in this thread ([MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)) long enough, I came up with this:

```
SELECT
  CAL.DATE,
  t.* EXCEPT (DATE)
FROM  
  CALENDER_TABLE AS CAL
LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT 
        CAL.DATE,
        CAL.DAY,
        SALES.ITEM,
        SALES.PROGRAM,
        SALES.SALE_DT,
        SALES.EFF_BGN_DT,
        SALES.EFF_END_DT
      FROM 
        CALENDAR_TABLE AS CAL
      LEFT JOIN 
        SALES_TABLE AS SALES
      ON CAL.DATE = SALES.SALE_DT
      WHERE 1=1
        and SALES.ITEM = 1 or SALES.ITEM is null
      ORDER BY DATE ASC) **t**
ON CAL.DATE = t.DATE
```

From what I can tell, it seems to be what I needed. It allows for the subquery to connect a date to all those records, then just joins on the calendar table again solely on date to allow for those nulls to be created.