# add x number of working days to date

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I am trying to find the date after specific number of days.
My query looks like this:

```
UPDATE [PST].[dbo].[tbl_Project_tracker1]
SET    Predicted_Eng_Comp_date = tb2.Predicted_Eng_Comp_date
FROM   (SELECT NETWORK_NO, 
        dateadd(DAY, 20, Actual_Eng_Start_date) as Predicted_Eng_Comp_date
        FROM   [PST].[dbo].[tbl_Project_tracker1] 
       ) as tb2
WHERE  [NETWORK_NO] = tb2.[NETWORK_NO]
```

The query works fine but i am looking for working days. How do i calculate that?

Comment: Define working days

Comment: add sample data and expected result please

Comment: Maybe this related question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20595934/1595345

Comment: You need a Calendar table first that differentiates working days for your culture. Once you have that, you can add pick the working day row that comes after 20 other working days.

Comment: You can store your working days in a separate table and compare them or you can write a function or a stored procedure to filter these values against your working days.

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of below Query (Which replaces your current query):

```
    UPDATE [PST].[dbo].[tbl_Project_tracker1] SET Predicted_Eng_Comp_date = DATEADD(DAY, 20, Actual_Eng_Start_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. Praveen your solution works perfectly thanks